# Modal not closing entirely on Leaflet JS Map

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, modal-dialog

I have a Leaflet EasyButton on my map which when clicked displays a modal which will eventually contain information about a country

I have taken the modal code from W3 schools https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp, and whilst it successfully opens, it doesn't seem to close fully when the x is clicked or outside of the modal.

See the pics below

**When button is clicked and modal appears**
[image]

**When modal is exited**
[image]

Once the modal is exited, there still appears to be the translucent film over the screen and nothing is clickable

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>Gazetteer Project</title>


  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Raleway:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i|Poppins:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Vendor CSS Files -->
  <link href="assets/vendor/aos/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Template Main CSS File -->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <!-- W3 Schools -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  
  <!-- Leaflet -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-sA+zWATbFveLLNqWO2gtiw3HL/lh1giY/Inf1BJ0z14=" crossorigin=""/>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.2/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-o9N1jGDZrf5tS+Ft4gbIK7mYMipq9lqpVJ91xHSyKhg=" crossorigin=""></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
   <link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-easybutton@2.0.0/src/easy-button.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>

   
   <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
  <!-- =======================================================
  * Template Name: Maxim - v4.9.1
  * Template URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/maxim-free-onepage-bootstrap-theme/
  * Author: BootstrapMade.com
  * License: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
  ======================================================== -->
</head>

<body>

  <!-- ====== Modals ===== -->
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
      </div>

    </div>

  
  <!-- ======= Header ======= -->
  <header id="header" class="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">

      <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="index.html">Geographical Gazetteer</a></h1>
      </div>
      

      <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
      

        <ul>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Drop Down</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
          </li>
                
                <select id="innerSelect">
                  
                  
                </select>
              </div>
        <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>

        </div>
      </nav>

  </header>
  
  
  <!-- ======= Map ======= -->
  <div id="container">
 <div id='map'></div>
    <!-- Modal -->

      
      


  <!-- ======= Footer ======= -->
<!---REMEMBER TO ADD IN BOOTSTRAP CREDITS--->

  <a href="#" class="back-to-top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up-short"></i></a>

  <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
  <script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>

  <!-- Template Main JS File -->
  <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>


  <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/functionality.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
L.easyButton('fa-comment-o', function(btn, map) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}, 'Informacije').addTo(map);


// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];


// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: where is the code reproducing the problem?

Comment: Did you add the javascript properly?

Comment: Code included in question now @kboul

Comment: again, with this code the problem is not reproduced

Comment: @kboul thats the full HTML - what else do you need?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change:

```
L.easyButton('fa-comment-o', function(btn, map) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}, 'Informacije').addTo(map);
```

to:

```
L.easyButton('fa-comment-o', function(btn, map) {
        modal.style.display = "block";
}).addTo(map);
```